# Elaboracion de boton con el siguiente estilo

Tags: botón, diseño, estilos

Buen día solicito amablemente por favor me expliquen como puedo hacer un botón con el siguiente estilo. logo a la izquierda con borde redondo y titulo a la derecha.

Muchas Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, te escribo una que me parece sencilla y ocupa pocas líneas:

Ejemplo:

```css
.logo{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  justify-content:start;
  align-items:center;
}

.imagen{
  width:70px; /* dale el tamaño que necesites pero width y height deben ser iguales */
  height:70px;
  border-radius:70px; /* el mismo tamaño que width y height para hacer un círculo */
}

.texto{
  width:100px; /* el tamaño que quieras darle, en px o % o em o etc */
  background-color:darkgreen; /* el color que necesites */
  border-radius:0 50px 50px 0; /* para darle el borde derecho redondo */
  padding: 1rem auto 1rem 2rem /* escribe números menores o mayores para darle los márgenes al texto */
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">

   <div class="imagen">
      <img src="direccion-de-imagen.jpg" title="Logotipo" alt="Logo de gota de agua">
   </div>

   <div class="texto">
      Agua
   </div>

</div>
```

*Espero que te sirva, y si no, dímelo.*

Comment: amigo es que quiero que sea un boton completo, tanto la imagen como el texto. por que si son dos divs pero no me lleva a nada.

Answer (score 0):

¿Te refieres a un botón con la imagen del logo? Entonces puedes hacerlo así:

```
<button>
   <img src="ruta-de-tu-imagen.jpg" alt="Descripción del logo">
   Texto del botón si quieres escribir algo, o en blanco
</button>
```

o así

```
<button class="boton-con-imagen">Texto del botón o en blanco</button>

.boton-con-imagen {
   background-image: url('ruta-de-tu-imagen.jpg');
   background-size: cover; /* Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen al botón para que ocupe todo el botón */
   background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Evita la repetición de la imagen en el botón */
   text-indent: -9999px; /* Oculta el texto en el botón */
   border: none; /* Quita el borde del botón si lo necesitas */
}
```